# Self hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-data-factory

can the VM be on cloud and Self hosted Integration runtime could be installed over it, and then used to connect to on premises system with cloud

Answer (score 2):

As long as all network and port related configs are clear , you can access an On Prem database from a cloud VM. A SHIR acts as a gateway between ADF and network bound database.
So in case if the Azure VM is able to access On Prem database, you can install your SHIR on that VM and proceed.

But any reason why would you prefer that? There might be some latency issue compared to hosting a SHIR on an On Prem server itself